# Precision and Recall With A Binary Classifier

Tags: precision-recall

I want to calculate the precision and recall of my results, however, I'm a little confused on how to create the confusion matrix. I have a binary response either yes or no from my participants, however, the correct answer is always YES. Therefore, I can only calculate the true positive and false negative rate. How would I be able to calculate these performance metrics with only these rates available? I'm fairly new to this so please excuse me if the answer is very simple!

Answer (score 0):

The confusion matrix is used for model evaluation. In your case it sounds like you are taking a survey, rather than evaluating the fit of a model. What is your motivation for using a confusion matrix?

Anyways, in the case that the confusion matrix is indeed the desired evaluation metric.. Your data is severely imbalanced (in fact there is only one class represented, and the other class is not present at all). With such extremely "imbalanced" data there is nothing useful that can be gathered.